# Model entities with firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following situation:

I have a team entity, in each team we have one or more users.

At first I thought about creating an array of IDS inside team. And then download all team and use the javascript to go through these IDS and fetch the corresponding user.

Something like that:

```
"teams": { 
  "xxxxxxx": {
   "ids": [0: "bKvysPZZCudBKbbjLYV8ZKr1NUo1", 1: XOvysPZZCudBKbbjLYV8ZKr1NUo1]
  }
}
```

But I do not know if it is the best solution. I would like your opinion.
Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend making a dictionary of IDs where each ID maps with the boolean value of `true`. I.e.:

```
"team-users": {
    "team1": [
        "uid1": true,
        "uid2": true,
        ...
    ]
}
```

if you want to get a team that a user is a part of, then use a parallel structure in you database. Add the following node:

```
"user-teams": {
    "uid1": [
        "team1": true,
        "team2": true,
        ...
    ]
}
```

Reading from this separate node is faster than querying.

Comment: And to do a query of type: get a team from a certain user, in the uid case. I could do with the firebase or would I have to use the javascript?

Comment: Please check my modified answer.